# Font weight with external font

Tags: css, font-face

I'm working with an external font type for my website, I have the 3 ttf files, for normal, bold and italic styles.

I'm wondering if I can change the font weight, because I already tried to use the font-weight CSS property, but it seems that it only works for either normal or bold weight, so I cannot use any weight in between.

Is there any way to use other weight for my font? Do I need to include any extra files?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: Not too helpful, mate - he knows what the font-weight CSS property is, he's just needs an assist understanding how it all works.

Comment: Yes! I tried it already and just wanted to know if it would be possible to apply that css property to an external font!

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, you can't use other weights as is - you'll need more files. You can use normal and bold because you've included normal and bold font files. Other weights will require an accompanying font file as well.

For a visual, check out any of the fonts at Google Fonts: https://www.google.com/fonts

You'll notice there are multiple files, each representing a different font weight (and/or style, such as italic).

Comment: Ok! Understood! Thanks a lot! :)